# Copy/Paste on Lubuntu in a VirtualBox in Mac host

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, macosx

Virtual Box 6.1; guest OS: Lubuntu 20.04; host OS: Mac OS 12.5.1. VB GuestAdditions installed.

I'm trying to understand how copy/paste keyboard shortcuts work. From my research it seems that it's 'shift + control + c' to copy and 'shift + control + v' to paste. This seesm to work in the terminal but not in Gedit or Firefox.

In Gedit nothing happens and in Firefox shift + control + c opens the Web Dev tools and shift + control + v does nothing.

I'm managing by using right-click > copy etc but this is pretty tedious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut keys to copy/paste are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and to paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> like in other operating systems. <kbd>Shift</kbd> is added in terminals, because Ctrl keys have a traditional meaning in the terminal, which is preserved in a graphical terminal emulator.

Linux also has a "primary" clipboard. Text that is selected can be pasted elsewhere with a middle mouse button. There are no shortcut keys available for this clipboard.

Comment: Yes! Ctrl + C outside the terminal (cf. Command + C in MacOS, and Ctrl + shift + C IN the terminal). Thank you my friend, that has been driving me crazy!